# Best way to factor base class/interface(s) for multi-tier message objects?

Tags: c#, oop, soa, dto, object-oriented-analysis

Working with C#, ASP.NET, MVC, WCF, assume you have a non-public business logic service layer, and for security and other such reasons you have a gateway or facade layer that is exposing the same operations publicly.

Therefore, you have two tiers with essentially identical data transfer (request/repsonse) objects, except the public/exposed service tier needs to deal with a GUID representing the calling user, and the private/internal service tier needs to deal with a richer authentication ticket. This authentication ticket must not be exposed to the public tier.

```
PublicDto {
      Guid userGuid;
      string property1;
      ...
      string propertyN;
 }

PrivateDto {
      AuthenticationTicket authTicket;
      string property1;
      ...
      string propertyN;
 }
```

Is there an efficient way to derive a base class or utilize interfaces here in such a way as to shield the private AuthenticationTicket from the public tier but minimize the cutting and pasting of the differentiating properties between private and public DTOs?

Comment: Why not a `BaseDto` with all the common properties, then two derived classes, one `PublicDto` with `userGuid`, and one `PrivateDto` with `authTicket`?

Comment: There are dozens of DTOs, so this results in dozens*3 classes to represent them.

Answer (score 1):

Derive both from a common base class declaring only the common properties

```
public abstract class BaseDto {
    string property1;
    ...
    string propertyN;
} 

public class PublicDto : BaseDto {
      Guid userGuid;
}

private class PrivateDto : BaseDto {
      AuthenticationTicket authTicket;
}
```

---

UPDATE:

A completely different approach is to treat the properties in a generic way, if this is a feasible way because of serialization.

```
public class PublicDto {
      public Guid userGuid { get; set; }
      public Dictionary<string,string> Prop { get; }

      public PublicDto ()
      {
          Prop = new Dictionary<string,string>();
      }
}
```

Usage

```
dto = new PublicDto();
Prop["FirstName"] = "John";
Prop["LastName"] = "Doe";
```

---

UPDATE #2

## 1

You could just derive the private from the public dto. The Guid would remain unused in the private dto.

## 2

Generic solution

```
public class Dto<T> {
    public T ID { get; set; }

    string property1;
    ...
    string propertyN;
} 

var publicDto = new Dto<Guid>();
var privateDto = new Dto<AuthenticationTicket>();
```

Comment: There are dozens of DTOs, so this results in dozens*3 classes to represent them. Which I guess is not to say this is NOT the most efficient way to do it, but I was hoping there was something slicker/more efficient.

Comment: hrmmmmm that's an interesting thought, let me ponder that, thanks.

Comment: only downside I see right off is the fact that the private tier already utilizes the existing DTOs, so this still results in a lot of rewrite. the need here is to extend to the public tier while shielding the internal auth implementation.

Comment: purely generic might work well. wonder what the WSDL would end up looking like. investigating this and the interface option from IDisposable.

Comment: If generics represent a problem, it is still possible to derive non-generic classes from generic classes. `public class PublicDto : Dto<Guid> {   }`

Answer (score 1):

You could make a few interfaces and one set of DTOs, then just make sure that the correct interface is what you pass around.

```
public interface IAnyPublic { Guid user; }
public interface IAnyPrivate { AuthenticationTicket ticket; }
public interface IOneBase { int foo; string goo; }
public interface IOnePublic : IOneBase, IAnyPublic { } // nothing to add, sir!
public interface IOnePrivate : IOneBase, IAnyPrivate { } // nothing to add, sir!
public class OneBase : IOnePublic, IOnePrivate { /*implement*/ }
```

Now all you do is make sure your internal stuff is passing around `IOnePrivate` ( `IAnyPrivate`) if it needs the ticket (only the ticket). Likewise, the public stuff is passing around `IOnePublic` (`IAnyPublic`) if it needs the user (only the user).  Finally, the methods defined in terms of only the base only use `IOneBase`.

Comment: thanks Marc, this was something I had discussed with the person I'm working with on this as well, though not quite fully baked like this. this might work well.

Comment: and if you want to use existing DTOs, that's just one more thing to list in the OneBase inheritance chain (or you could play the partial class game to mix-in the stuff you want).

Comment: On other thing to consider, is exposing the Guid or AuthenticationTicket what you really need to do, or are you exposing some other slightly-more abstract interface that knows what to do with the underlying information?